# Routing to Firebase API when different users have same key value

Tags: routes, key, firebase

I have a Firebase API with different hospitals which each have their own ID. I have created routes to each hospital ID, so when you go to the page of that hospital, it shows all of their information. Now I want to be able to create routes to a specific value. So every hospital that has a key of "services" and a value of "MRI" it will route to a page where they are listed.

Help?

Comment: can you provide more info about your issue

Comment: Hi Kelsey, welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of describing your code, I recommend that you actually show us the code that is relevant to your question. Most likely the answer is simple, but it will be a lot clearer when we actually see what you've tried (instead of having to paint a picture about your code from your description of it). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve